# Multi stage amplifier

Tags: bjt

[image]

I have to find the Q point of the circuit, and then calculate its amplification parameters using small signal models. Both transistors must be in forward active mode to operate as amplifiers but if assume Q2 is in active mode (and therefore VE2B2 is roughly 0.8V),it leads me to a contradiction (VE2C2 turns out negative). Even without directly solving the circuit,something about this configuration seems a little odd to me.The current that flows through E2 has to be quite big and so the voltage drop across RC2,that makes Q2 remain in saturation even for small currents. If anything about my question is misunderstood,please let me to know and I'll try to clarify. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Alon, just saw this. A quick glance tells me that there's a serious problem with the 1 mA current source. If can't go out Q1's emitter -- 1000 V drop for its emitter resistor? It can't go out Q2's collector -- even 10 V voltage drop isn't possible. So much of that current has to go through to Q2's base, so Q2 is thoroughly saturated and it's collector will be held very close to, but just slightly above ground. And that also tells you where Q1's collector will be regardless of how the rest of Q1 settles out, DC wise. Maybe I should spend more than 5 seconds on this, though?

Comment: That assignment has been given as homework , When I'd seen that, I quickly concluded there is something wrong with this circuit. I sent a message to my tutor to make him aware of that..

Comment: Hopefully, your tutor has a brain and some time for you, as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

This design is not in a linear mode and cannot be with this arrangement.  There is no current sharing differential bias.

It is possible to consider fixing this design, but the assumptions are false.

[This is how I would fix it.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsB0Z-CEEYCmBaA7CAzADgEzQYBs%20kBSALNgJw1jGUjERKRT5TpJIBQALiHxhcIJDU75KrCeDEg0SaJVyVKSMNlL4kGSvnzZw0SDSTCwulnsiQtYuCAAmKAGYBDAK4AbfrwBOYvii4pxWYrKs8LwA7kIiIDTEQriiSeC8AEo49unY9oxyENJQRcaQWYnJoSAqEZystfDG8OwQ7Sa8AA44xCGyWqLCIbUZAPK9Q6m1dcGi7bFCJWTJc0KQyWCL2GBMKzmrGxlx%20dVqB2IkYgHxaasJNVGIN4MpQwlrEAYIsIgI2LwAOYXfanIQYBrHC5UPYlGFCXgASwueXs8I6cD4gTBwxBRyecEWUi%20H2WUgRAGMgv1OOlHi14EhynQMJBKMRaEhUiJyWBfli3vVBfsCdEenTZOk6aMtoFiUJyfKRQ4BIKamD6YoWtJWVRzHMRJpyWg%20WyMOZIFy7LgkjosBoIC4PD4-HE1qDdutNkTpqjkuktm64Vd5fC%20G6HrJwjV8Nt7LjXrjYyc%20rdJoLA2mYx9plsAPajJCbJo0eb874YTQWhlwGgkDZkOScJgAgvsItyahsoQmGtgOvEBtta4F6rFi3ssQmdSD9kYJLEFl1mtM1e8AvCMTjkh4Ta-XCmHjERdsNl9AgroRXzcAvAymttWDsACy7gAHgAdADOADU8753EBFBeCAA)

1. Delete C2
2. Reduce Re1 from 1k down towards Rbe to increase gain to 15 ohms +/-5.
3. Remove Q2 base shunt to ground and insert 250k (100k to 1M
4. Add Negative Feedback R = 150x Rs +/-20% to get an AC gain of 100
5. choose Ve1 = 1.5V